# Mapping a navigation property to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an `Application` class. Entity framework created a navigation property called `Assistants`.  When I run my web application `Assistants` is populated for me by the framework.

I wrote a stored procedure called `GetAssistantsByApplicationID`.  I need to map this stored procedure to the `Assistants` property and pass it the `applicationID` to bring back the assistants for that specific application.

How would I do this?  Am I doing it the correct way?

Here is my code from my repository class for getting the specific application:

```
public Application GetApplicationByID(int applicationID)
{
   var application =
      (from a
      in context.GetApplicationByID(applicationID)
      select a).FirstOrDefault();

   return application;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work because of something called 'Relationship Fixup':

```
public Application GetApplicationAndAssistantsByApplicationID(int applicationID)
{
   var application =
      (from a
      in context.GetApplicationByID(applicationID)
      select a).FirstOrDefault();

   // call your other stored procedure...
   var assistants = context.GetAssistantsByApplicationID(applicationID)
                           .ToArray();
   // as the assistants are materialized they will automatically show up
   // in application.Assistants too.

   return application;
}
```